# Efficient way to implement multidimentional data in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, implementation

I am looking for a way to implement this multi dimensional data in Java. Very similar examples are shown in these pics.

I know that databases are probably better, but for the sake learning Java, I am looking to implement this in Java first.

Any advice or as to what methods to look for is appreciated.

[image: an example]

[image: an example]

Comment: For the first image, I'd say a Hashmap from integer to some list of Person objects with the integer being the year. Not sure what the second picture is showing

Comment: There are many ways. Choosing a data structure always requires also knowledge of the operations that should be supported by it.

Comment: It really depends on what you need to do with these data. How will you be searching into ?

Comment: Looks like HashMap (as cricket noted), but with key as an selfwritten Object (e.g. containing name, year, attribute).

Comment: I guess the second would be a City object with a map between the date and some PC object with a description and a value

Comment: Thanks for the answers. In the future I am planning to analyze the data based on past and current values to show trends. But that's a long term goal which I am far away from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer to your question it is necessary to know some additional informations:

- Are the possible values of each dimension fixed or not?
- Are values sparse or not?
- Are possible values of each dimension with a very long range or not?

If you have **few possible fix values** for each dimension you can use a **multimensional array**.

If you have **few possible non fixed values** for each dimension you can consider **`List` of `List` of `List`...**

If you have **many possible values and a sparse matrix** you can use a **`Map<Coordinate, Value>`** where `Coordinate` is a class representing a single coordinate to find your value and `Value` is the type of your values.

Comment: At the moment I just want to test the waters to see possible implementations and try them out. So answering your question, currently the data on the first picture is all I need. Ideally in the future, there would be 20000 entries for which a DB is necessary I believe. (OLAP i guess)

Comment: If you have also only 1000 possible values for each dimension having 4 dimensions means 1000^4 possible coordinates, so 1.000.000.000.000 for such systems often the sparse matrix is the best solution because not all values are generally fitted.